# Comparison of two proper times in Special Relativity using an in-between frame

Tags: special-relativity

I would like to compare two proper times of two inertial observers in Special Relativity.

Let's consider three inertial observers A, O and B freely moving on a line in a flat space-time, with B moving with a constant velocity $v$ with respect to A and O moving with a constant velocity $w$ with respect to A.

In the rest frame of O, A will move with the velocity $-w$ (always), and, by choosing $w$ carefully, B can move with the same velocity but in the opposite direction (+$w$). I just created an in-between frame in which the situation is symmetrical. Applying the basic time dilation formula in the rest frame of O for A and B respectively, I find $d\tau_{A} = d\tau_{B}$.

*Mathematical proof*

I want the velocity of O seen from B to be $-w$. I therefore need to solve the following system based on the velocity addition formula:
$$ -w = \frac{w-v}{1-\frac{wv}{c^{2}}}$$

This leads to

$$w = \frac{c^{2}}{v}\left(1-\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^{2}}\right)$$

In the rest frame of O associated with the coordinate time $t_{o}$, we have:

$$d\tau_{A} = \frac{dt_{o}}{\gamma(-w)}$$
$$d\tau_{B} = \frac{dt_{o}}{\gamma(w)}$$

With $\tau_{A}$ and $\tau_{B}$ the proper times of A and B, and $\gamma(w) = 1/\sqrt{1-(w/c)^{2}}$

Leading to $d\tau_{A} = d\tau_{B}$. Ok.

Now let's go back in the rest frame of A. We associate a coordinate time $t$ to it. We therefore have:

$$d\tau_{B} = \frac{dt}{\gamma(v)}$$

Similarly, in the rest frame of B associated with a coordinate time $t'$ :

$$d\tau_{A} = \frac{dt'}{\gamma(-v)}$$

Which leads to $dt=dt'$. Or we know that:

$$dt' = \gamma(v)(dt-\frac{v}{c^{2}}dx)$$

It seems like there is an inconsistency. Please let me know what is wrong, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please let me know what is wrong, thank you!

Nothing is wrong. $\gamma$ is an even function, as you have shown

> It seems like there is an inconsistency.

The inconsistency in your edit is the pairs of events that you are choosing to compare.

When you use simultaneity in the middle frame to select the events on the clocks then you get that the pair had equal proper time. That pair of events will have equal proper time in all frames, but will only be simultaneous in in the middle frame.

When you use simultaneity in the A frame to select the events on the clocks then you will get that the B clock had less proper time. With that pair of events the B clock will have less proper time in all frames, but will only be simultaneous in the A frame.

Comment: But I have just proved that the rate of the clocks of A and B is the same. If the twins do not accelerate, they have the same age... why so much discussion about time dilation problems ? Why no text book ever told me that $dtau_{A}=dtau_{B}$ ? Why this calculation is not in the litterature just after the introduction of the lorentz transformations ?

Comment: Please find my edit to show you the inconsistency.

Comment: @FrançoisRitter: The typical twin paradox scenario is not symmetrical. One of the twins turns around and travels back to meet up with the other twin. If you integrate $d\tau$ for each twin's path you will find that the total elapsed time is shortest for the twin that stays in the same inertial frame the whole time. The shape of the path between two points in spacetime affects the proper time for a traveler on that path.

Comment: Yes I do agree. What about the inconsistency dt=dt' at the end of my post? Thank you

Comment: There is no inconsistency. A and B don't have the same notion of simultaneous events, so there is no problem having each twin observing the other's clock going slower.

Comment: I don't understand. Lorentz transformation gives dt'=gamma(v)(dt-vdx/c^2) and I just shown that dt'=dt ?

Comment: @cuspy You got the twin paradox backwards. The stay at home twin ages more than the twin who travels in 2 (or more) frames. That's because of the -+++ metric signature of Minkowski spacetime.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Oops! You're right of course. I meant longest. Too late to edit now.

Comment: @Cuspy Code 18: "Too late to edit now" But you can always  delete a comment & then write a new one.

Comment: @Dale Thank you for your answer, but I am confused now. Is it wrong to say that $d\tau_{A} = d\tau_{B}$ all the time ? Am I allowed to say that constant velocity in one direction does not change the proper rate of a clock ? I don't understand why the simultaneity has something to do with this equality, because I am only interested in the time difference between the events, not their specific start in a frame. Could you detail your answer and indicate me where my reasonning is wrong? Thank you :)

Comment: You say you are “only interested in the time difference between the events” but the question is which events? The events you are picking are different in the different frames, hence the inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

$\let\D=\Delta \let\g=\gamma \def\rA{{\mathrm A}} 
\def\rB{{\mathrm B}}$ 
Your problem is that you make a too casual use of $d\tau=dt/\g$. You'd
keep in mind its meaning.

If there are two (inertial) frames, A and B, what do you mean by
"proper times of A and B"? Time is always measured between two events
E, F. And for the same events you may measure time in both frames. The
difference is whether E and F happen in the same place of A or of B
(or possibly neither).

Proper time of A can only mean time measured in A for events E, F
having a common position in A. If you measure the time interval between
E and F with B's clocks, you'll find 
$$\D t_{\rB} = \g\,\D t_\rA$$
and only $\D t_\rA$ is proper time. If E, F have same position in B,
then the opposite holds:
$$\D t_{\rA} = \g\,\D t_\rB$$
with the same $\g=\g(v)=\g(-v)$,